# scikit-learn pipeline _transform() takes 'x' positional arguments but 'y' were given

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**The Problem:**

I'm designing a custom transformer using scikit-learn's pipeline, but am having positional argument mismatch. The class I've defined is:

```
class DataSubsetGenerator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, sub_percentage, random_state = 42):
        self.sub_percentage = sub_percentage
        self.random_state = random_state
    def fit(self):
        return self
    def transform(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        # Do data processing stuff here, removed to simplify example here...
        return X_train_sub, X_test_sub, y_train_sub, y_test_sub
```

I then put this into a 1-step custom pipeline to test out:

```
reduce_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('Prototype dataset', DataSubsetGenerator(0.5, random_state = random_state))
])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = reduce_pipeline.transform(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

And I receive the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-4b2a20eb8b63> in <module>()
      3 ])
      4 
----> 5 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = reduce_pipeline.transform(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

TypeError: _transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

This makes no sense, because I've defined the `transform()` function of the `DataSubGenerator` class to take 4 arguments.

**My Testing:**

I've tested this without using sklearn's pipeline by instantiating `DataSubGenerator` and calling `transform()` and it functions according to design:

```
dsg = DataSubsetGenerator(0.5, random_state = random_state)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = dsg.transform(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

***My question is: Why isn't the `transform()` function recognizing these 4 arguments when used in an sklearn pipeline?***

**Related Q&A:**

I've tried researching, and the closest Q&A thread is this: [_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363650/transform-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given). However, I'm not able to understand the solution and how it applies to my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises due to this [line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/pipeline.py#L552). Here, the expectation is that you will feed only `X` when the final step of your pipeline have `transform` method, which means it is inherited from regressorMixin or classifierMixin.

First, we need to understand that sklearn's estimators follow the API design of `(X, y)`. Thats the reason for the pipeline API design as well.

Hence, you do the data splitting or sampling before feeding it into the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I've fixed this now by requiring that the transform() method accept a single list (of dataframes) and also returns a corresponding list. For sklearn pipelines, is this the commonly-accepted means to accept and return a list, if multiple items are required?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this by modifying the transformer class to take in, and return a **single** list (containing multiple dataframes):

```
class DataSubsetGenerator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, sub_percentage, random_state = 42):
        self.sub_percentage = sub_percentage
        self.random_state = random_state
    def fit(self):
        return self
    def transform(self, dataframes):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = dataframes
        # Do data processing stuff here, removed to simplify example here...
        return [X_train_sub, X_test_sub, y_train_sub, y_test_sub]
```

Feel free to let me know if there's a better solution, or a commonly-accepted pattern.